# hadoop: reading files from a distributedCache

Tags: hadoop

I have put a file in distributedCache in this way:

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(pathU.toString()),job2.getConfiguration());
```

and in my mapper, in setup() function, I am reading it in this way:

```
localFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(localFiles[0].toString());
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);

for (int i = 0; i < uMat.getMatrix().length; i++) {
   double d = dis.readDouble();
   uMat.getMatrix()[i] = d;
 }
```

but always the first double I read, is a random negative number! why is that? where does it come from? The rest of the doubles i read are correct (they are what i expect them to be)

any idea?

Comment: Have you opened this file with a text editor, or at least seen the first few lines with `head` command? Perhaps the problem is when you write this file.